# How to create objects in java fx based on user input (user inputs stuff in textfields, event is created)

Tags: java, javafx

Part of an app im making (uni project) involves an event list where a user can create a calendar event, give it a name/date/time etc and there's a schedule scrollable list that displays all of this.

The way ive got it right now - the user enters event info in an alertbox -  [screenshot of how alertbox looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejhqD.png)  - then the alertbox (AddEventAlertBox class) creates an 'Event' object (Event class) with given info and the main window (EventScreen class) displays the event in a chronological list. However I'm not sure how to create events then pass them back to the event screen. Here's what I think is the relevant code to the question.

Event class:

```
//Arraylist to store all events created
protected List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
//constructor to initialise event values, add event object to list
public Event(String name, String type, String date, int startTime, int duration) {
    eventName = name;
    eventType = type;
    eventDate = date;
    eventStartTime = startTime;
    eventDuration = duration;

    eventList.add(this);

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

EventScreen Class:
[Heres what it looks like when run, under 'events coming up' I want to add a list of events.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioTQr.png)

AddEventAlertBox class:

```
    //Create save button to create event object with given information.
    Button saveButton = new Button("Save");
    saveButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        new Event(eventName.getText(), eventtype.getText(), eventDate.getText(), Integer.parseInt(eventStartTime.getText()), Integer.parseInt(eventDuration.getText()));
        window.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your challenge is to pass a reference to the newly created "Event" object inside the alert box back to the EventScreen - or to be more generic: To pass an object reference from a dialog window back to the main window.

The new Event object you are creating in the "setOnAction" lambda in the alert box class should be stored in a field inside that class, so you can easily access it after it has been created. Create a new method in that class that returns the new Event - something like

```
public Event getCreatedEvent() { 
    return this.createdEvent; // This is the field where you store the new Event
}
```

This new method should then be called from the EventScreen class right after the AddEventAlertBox window has been closed - wherever that is. The result can then be added to the eventList, which I assume is in the EventScreen class.